# Windows Server 2008 r2 won't accept local connections via IP but external connections are fine?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 running remote desktop for me to connect to from my Windows 7 laptop when I am out of the office.

So when I am at home, I can log into the server using remote desktop via the IP address of the server just fine.

Now when I take my laptop to the office, on the server's local network, it won't let me connect via IP, like it *used* to. It will connect perfectly fine using the machine name, however.

This just started happening on Friday - I connected to the server Friday morning via IP from the local network. A few hours later, it would no longer accept connections via IP address, even though I had changed nothing!

Comment: Sounds like the DHCP lease expired, give it a static IP on your local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to resolve its self after a recent Windows Update. I don't know which update it was that fixed it and I still don't know what the issue(s) was/were.